# Denoising autoencoder - training with added noise on custom interval

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to understand denoising autoencoders. I've followed this keras tutorial - https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

In the tutorial, the training data is created by adding an artificial noise in the following way:

```
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape) 
x_test_noisy = x_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_test.shape)
```

which produces:

[image]

Which means the noise as well as the underlying data from MINST dataset have values between 0 and 1.

After applying the trained model, most of the noise is correctly removed:
[image]

---

I'm trying to train the model with only very little artificial noise, but on interval -5 to 5 as following:

```
def noise_matrix(arr, num, min, max):
    m = np.product(arr.shape)
    arr.ravel()[np.random.randint(0, m, size=num)] = np.random.uniform(min, max, num)
    return arr

x_train_noisy = noise_matrix(x_train, x_train.shape[0] * 2, -5, 5)
x_test_noisy = noise_matrix(x_test, x_test.shape[0] * 2, -5, 5)
```

which produces:

[image]

(Differences in contrast in the above picture is caused by implicit normalization in `matplotlib` library)

Now, when I train the autoencoder and apply the model, I'm getting the following result:

[image]

Most of the noise is not removed. What steps do I need to do in order to remove the noise from interval `(-5,5)`? I've tried to normalize all the data after adding noise to interval `(0,1)` but this is not the way to go (I was getting very bad results with this approach).

Answer (score 0):

The decoded image still has obvious noises. Since you did not provide the code used to fit the autoencoder, I am guessing that you are fitting it on the noised data `ae.fit(x=x_noised, y=x_noised)`, 
whereas you should be fitting on the original data:

```
ae.fit(x=x_noised, y=x_original)
```